# Subtracting months - issue with last day of month?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Quick question on dates in R. Check out this snippet of code:

```
Sys.Date() - months(3)
# [1] "2013-12-31"
Sys.Date() - months(18)
# [1] NA
```

I've loaded the package `lubridate` and followed [the instructions provided](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/03/do-more-with-dates-and-times-in-r-with-lubridate-1-1-0/) , and I can't quite get my head around this behavior. It used to work just fine, today's the first day that I've noticed that a subtraction of more than 12 months from today's date yields `NA` (subtracting less than 12 months works fine).

I'd appreciate if anyone can explain to me why this isn't working, and/or suggest a more "robust" way around it. Does it have something to do with today being the last day of the month (day 31)?

I'm asking because this works:

```
Sys.Date() - years(2)
# [1] "2012-03-31"
```

Comment: This is indeed an "is there a 31st in this month?" issue: `lapply(1:18, function(x) Sys.Date()-months(x))`

Comment: A workarounds include: `seq(Sys.Date(), length = 2, by = "-18 months")` or `library(mondate); as.Date(as.mondate(Sys.Date()) - 18)` which resolve the ambiguity in two different ways.

Comment: If you are looking for a monthly data oriented solution, also check out `library(xts); as.yearmon(Sys.Date()) - 1:18/12`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `lubridate` functions `%m+%` and `%m-%` are designed to handle this issue ("Add and subtract months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month").

```
library(lubridate)
Sys.Date() %m-% months(18)
# [1] "2012-09-30"

# or to make it reproducible if Sys.Date() happens to be different from that in OP
as.Date("2014-03-31") %m-% months(18)
# [1] "2012-09-30"

# example of %m+%
as.Date("2014-01-31") + months(1)
# [1] NA
as.Date("2014-01-31") %m+% months(1)
# [1] "2014-02-28"
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provides forward months **exactly**, i.e. 28Feb %m+% gives 28Mar, which is not ideal if working with month end data.

To adjust the top to always give you the **last day of the month**, use the following code:

```
ceiling_date((as.Date("2014-02-28") %m+% months(1)),"month")-days(1)

> "2014-03-31"
```

Comment: Many years later, this is still my preferred solution to the problem. `%m-%` or `%m+%` by themselves do not solve the issue of getting the precise month end when you start with non-31 days-months. If you do `as.Date("2021-06-30") %m-% months(3)` you will get 2021-03-30 and not the 2021-03-31 you need. 
Applying the suggestion above you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly if you want to have an increment of 3 months, it can be done as follows:

```
PW_Data_Plan_V1$Month = as.Date(PW_Data_Plan_V1$DOJ) %m+% months(3)
```